# How to create a new environment from the environment.yml file?

Tags: git, python-3.x, anaconda, conda

Please pardon me if this is a very silly question. I am new to Anadonda. While I am able to create an environment from the GUI (Anaconda Navigator), but I am unable to follow the steps given to me.

```
git clone https://XXX/Some_Example.git
cd Some_Example
```

This above step I have successfully executed. I can see "Some_Example.git" is in my C:\ Drive.

Then it says,If you are on Windows, rename

```
meta_windows_patch.yml to
meta.yml
```

**I could not find this "meta_windows_patch.yml" file anywhere.**

Then it says, Create "Some_Example". Running this command will create a new conda environment that is provisioned with all libraries you need to be successful in this program. Run the following code

```
conda env create -f environment.yml
```

Now, my problem is 
**1) I am not able to find the "environment.yml" in my entire computer. I searched everywhere !!**

Comment: Without including which git repository this is, it is impossible to help...

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you do. Step by step.

You open your command prompt.

1. Go to : C:>git clone https://github.com/udacity/CarND-Term1-Starter-Kit-Test-git
2. C:>cd CarND-Term1-Starter-Kit

3.C:\CarND-Term1-Starter-Kit>dir

4.You will see the list of files. It will include the file you are looking for.

5.C:\CarND-Term1-starter-kit>rename meta_windows_patch.yml meta.yml

6.Go to the directory now. You will see the changed file name!